# gwt Composite open/visible handler

Tags: gwt, handler, composite

I have got several Composite and I would like to add an Handler to one of them which fire an event if the user open this composite. Is there any Handler for?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A good/easy way to fire events is by the use of the GQuery library, which emulates JQuery in GWT code.
It allows you to do things like:

```
$(yourWidget).blur();
```

to fire a blur event on yourWidget, for example... if you don't mind adding a dependency to GQuery to your project, this is the way to go in my opinion.
You can even provide a Function which will be called after the event has fired, as in:

```
$(yourWidget).click(new Function() {
  public boolean f(Event e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

I am not sure how you would do that in pure GWT, but it's obviously possible... you may want to see how GQuery does that.

http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/

Comment: Hmm that sounds a little bit complex. I think there must be an easier solution for. I explain it in another words.  I have got a tab with several Composites on it. When a user click on one of them, the Composite is shown to the user. In this Case I would like to start a method, but I doesn't know if there is any Handler for..

Comment: What is the type of your TabPanel? For example, if it's a TabLayoutPanel, you can add a SelectionHandler<Integer> to it by calling addSelectionHandler(..). The onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer>) method will be called every time the user changes the tab. You can then do whatever you want, like populate one of your Composites dynamically.

Comment: But anyway, if someone clicks on your Composite, you say the Composite is shown to the user... What do you mean? The Composite gets larger??? Or a Composite is created and shown?? In either case, you must be picking up the onClick event?! Or your problem is to get the click event???